# Datetime conversion - convert only date for rows not containing time

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, datetime

I have the dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
            'ID': ['AB01', 'AB02', 'AB03', 'AB04','AB05', 'AB06'],
            'l_date': ["1/4/2021","1/4/2021",'1/5/2021','1/5/2021','1/8/2021', np.nan],
            'l_time': ["17:05",
                      "6:00","13:43:10","00:00",np.nan,np.nan]
    }
    )
```

And I want to create a new column which combines `l_date` and `l_time` into a datetime column, `l_datetime`.

My code is this

```
cols = ['l_date','l_time']
df['d_datetime'] = df[cols].astype(str).agg(' '.join, axis=1)
df['d_datetime'] = df['d_datetime'].replace({'nan':''},  regex=True) 
df['d_datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['d_datetime'], errors="coerce").dt.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
```

Now, this generates time for `AB05` as `00:00` and creates the datetime. But for the ones which doesn't time in column `l_time`, I want the `d_datetime` to only have the date. How can I achieve this?

Intially I tried

```
df['d_datetime'] = df['d_datetime'].replace({' 00:00':''},  regex=True)
```

But this removes the time for `AB04` too and I don't want that. How can I achieve the end result looks like below?

[image]

**UPDATE**
From the below result:

[image]

I want to check if `l_time` is `NaN` and if it is then, I want to apply `replace({'00:00':''})` to that row. How can I achieve this?

Comment: @MrFuppes This doesn't work. I need `05/01/2021 00:00` for `AB04` and `1/8/2021` for `AB05`

Comment: @MrFuppes Why are your comments deleted? I was just trying to get it done with ur offer plus the `loc` for str.replace without success... could you please go more into detail what the syntax would be with `loc`?

Comment: @Rabinzel I removed them because I think they were misleading. MuhammadHassan's answer seems to give what the OP needs I think.

Comment: @Rabinzel I have updated the question, how can I apply the new if condition?

Comment: I think you wanted to ask @MrFuppes or somebody else, because I'm myself only learning working with pandas, sorry. I was just curious where to add the `loc` in MrFuppes solution to make it work regardless to the already given option by Muhammad

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
df['d_datetime'] = (pd.to_datetime(df['l_date']).dt.strftime("%d/%m/%Y") + ' ' +
                    pd.to_datetime(df['l_time']).dt.time.replace(np.nan, '').astype(str).str[0:5]).str.strip()
```

`OUTPUT:`

```
     ID    l_date    l_time        d_datetime
0  AB01  1/4/2021     17:05  04/01/2021 17:05
1  AB02  1/4/2021      6:00  04/01/2021 06:00
2  AB03  1/5/2021  13:43:10  05/01/2021 13:43
3  AB04  1/5/2021     00:00  05/01/2021 00:00
4  AB05  1/8/2021       NaN        08/01/2021
5  AB06       NaN       NaN               NaN
```

Comment: Hi, can you help me understand what happens here `df['l_time'].replace(np.nan, '').str[0:5]).str.strip()`

Comment: This `pd.to_datetime(df['l_time']).dt.time` line convert s `l_time` column to `datetime` and then extracts just `time`, it will create `NaN` for lines where `l_time` does not exist. Then we have to use this `.replace(np.nan, '')` so that when we add `l_date` and `l_time` we don't have `NaN` at the end. Then we use this `.astype(str).str[0:5]` to get just minutes and seconds part. Lastly after adding two columns, use this `.str.strip()` to remove any trailing spaces from the final column.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
            'ID': ['AB01', 'AB02', 'AB03', 'AB04','AB05', 'AB06'],
            'l_date': ["1/4/2021","1/4/2021",'1/5/2021','1/5/2021','1/8/2021', np.nan],
            'l_time': ["17:05",
                      "6:00","13:43:10","00:00",np.nan,np.nan]
    }
    )
df.l_time = df.l_time.fillna('')
df['d_datetime']= df['l_date'].astype(str)+" "+ df['l_time'].astype(str)
print(df)
```

Comment: Yes @Vivs, I have a format to which I need to convert to

Comment: i made small change to add space.

Comment: I have updated the question, how can I apply the new if condition?

Answer (score 0):

```
df.loc[df["l_time"].isnull(), "d_datetime"] = df["d_datetime"].replace(
    {"00:00": ""}, regex=True
)
```